# Should a Kickstarter funding be in an academic CV?

Tags: cv, humanities

In humanities, would a successful kickstarter project which supported relevant professional work belong in an academic CV? I think a "grants and fundraisers" category can have crowdfunding, but my friend thinks not. This is in the context of faculty job application in the US.

Comment: How much money did you raise?

Comment: @DanRomik Let's say $10k for a production of an art project.

Comment: That's a pretty nice amount. I'd say put it in, it probably won't help you very much, but can't hurt, and could serve as a useful icebreaker/conversation starter in an interview setting or at a conference etc. Besides, you never know who's checking out your CV online and may approach you some day asking for advice, a collaboration, or wanting help with their own Kickstarter project that involves much bigger amounts of money. Bottom line is, you did it, and it was to support an academic professional activity, so it certainly sounds relevant to me. Disclaimer: I'm in math not the humanities.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since we're talking about the humanities, let me answer with a Simpsons quote:

> Ned Flanders: I don't understand. Is God punishing me?
>
> Reverend Lovejoy: Short answer, "yes" with an "if"; long answer, "no," with a "but"

I believe that academic CVs should be tailored to the requirements of the situation. If you're applying for a faculty position in the Department of Film and Media Studies, a Kickstarter campaign in which you raised money for an independent movie is appropriate. Otherwise, adding this information is about as useful as saying that you like pina coladas and getting caught in the rain.

---

PS. If you were [Zack Danger Brown](https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/zackdangerbrown/potato-salad), I'd hire you right away if I was head of Social Psychology or Cultural Studies.

PPS. Thank god, I'm not head of an academic department.